# Create a search engine using python ( search from an XML file only )

Tags: python

I have details like this on an XML file

```
<note>
<id>51</id>
<Name>Jani</Name>
<city>Frankfurt</city>
<IQ>Intelligent</IQ>
</note>

<note>
<id>71</id>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<city>Paris</city>
<IQ>Average</IQ>
</note>

<note>
<id>81</id>
<Name>Asho</Name>
<city>Paris</city>
<IQ>Intelligent</IQ>
</note>
```

Given these details, I want to implement a search engine that should enable the user to search for all the `'Intelligent'` people in the file.

Kindly suggest me the best way to do it in python.

Comment: You are about to search the file or search in file ?

Comment: You can use xml.etree.elementtree for parsing the xml and then search for `Intelligent` people http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: @Vash, search in the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: @Vash, I do not just want to count, but to get all the information of the 'intelligent' people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de) and XPath:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

xml = """<root>
<note>
<id>51</id>
<Name>Jani</Name>
<city>Frankfurt</city>
<IQ>Intelligent</IQ>
</note>

<note>
<id>71</id>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<city>Paris</city>
<IQ>Average</IQ>
</note>

<note>
<id>81</id>
<Name>Asho</Name>
<city>Paris</city>
<IQ>Intelligent</IQ>
</note>

</root>"""

tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(xml))
for note in tree.xpath("//note[IQ='Intelligent']"):
    print note.getchildren()[1].tag + "=" + note.getchildren()[1].text
```

This prints:

```
Name=Jani
Name=Asho
```

Comment: I want the search engine to get all the information of all the 'Intelligent' people, so that I can access it to use for some other purpose.

Comment: You can do that. Just access the information of each `note`. See the lxml documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is small them the libary xml.mindom can give you an easy to transvert data structure
if the file is larger I would suggest xml.etree.cElementTree

alternativly you could preparse your file as needed, for example:
make a dict (or list if all numeric ids are used) that has tuples/list with relevant data
then make a name, city and IQ dict that contains lists with ids such that:

note[51] = (51,'Jani', 'Frankfurt', 'Intelligent')

and

iq_dict['Intelligent'] = (81, 51)

etc..